# Trying to get an existing document in my collection but it returns the DocumentSnapshot as null. Any clues?

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to get a document from my collection of "users" however it returns it as null. Please have a look at my collection and documents
[My collection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uwsMD.png)

And following is my code

```
private void gettingCurrentUser(){
        String currentUserEmail = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser().getEmail();
        DocumentReference docRef = firebaseFirestore.collection("users").document(currentUserEmail);
        docRef.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DocumentSnapshot> task) {
                if(task.isSuccessful()) {
                    DocumentSnapshot document = task.getResult();
                    if(document.exists()) {

                        test = document.getString("FirstName");

                    }
                    else {
                       Log.e(TAG, "Error message", task.getException());
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

I have tried getting every field one by one as well but it is of no use

```
 private void gettingCurrentUser(){
    String currentUserEmail = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser().getEmail();
    DocumentReference docRef = firebaseFirestore.collection("users").document(currentUserEmail);
    docRef.get().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot) {

            String firstName = documentSnapshot.getData().get("FirstName").toString();
            String lastName = documentSnapshot.getData().get("LastName").toString();
            String emailAddress = documentSnapshot.getData().get("EmailAddress").toString();
            String dob = documentSnapshot.getData().get("DOB").toString();
            String address1 = documentSnapshot.getData().get("Address1").toString();
            String address2 = documentSnapshot.getData().get("Address2").toString();
            String city = documentSnapshot.getData().get("City").toString();
            String country = documentSnapshot.getData().get("Country").toString();
            String phonenumber = documentSnapshot.getData().get("Phonenumber").toString();

            User user = new User(firstName, emailAddress, lastName, phonenumber, address1, address2, city, country,dob);

            adminUser = user;

        }
    });
}
```

I think it is to do with some asynchronous call to my collection but I am not sure. As you can see in my [log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CWZ2L.png) it does return the document but for some reason is always null when assigning it the "adminUser". I would really appreciate if you could help me and give me a few pointers on async calls too. Thank you so much in advance!

---

The following is the link to my log when I try to get the document from a collection

https://wetransfer.com/downloads/2a134aa1396050585b18fa756fd7f48320190401143731/20844c

---

The following is my code for getting the user's first name in one of my activities and it works fine

```
 private void gettingData() {
   FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
   String userEmail = user.getEmail();
   final DocumentReference docRef = firebaseFirestore.collection("users").document(userEmail);
   final String docPath = docRef.getPath();
   docRef.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
       @Override
       public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DocumentSnapshot> task) {
           if (task.isSuccessful()) {
               DocumentSnapshot document = task.getResult();
               if(document.exists()) {
                   Log.d(TAG, "Document Snapshot data: " + document.getData());
                   firstName = document.getData(). get("FirstName").toString();
                   textViewFirstName.setText("Welcome " + firstName);
               } else {
                   Log.d(TAG, "No such document");
               //    Toast.makeText(Home.this, "Failed Registration:2 "+task.getException(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
               }
           } else {
               Log.d(TAG, "get failed with ", task.getException());
               //Toast.makeText(Home.this, "Failed Registration:3 "+task.getException(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
           }
       }
   });
}
```

Comment: is your `onSuccess` even triggered? Try to put a simple log statement, is it displayed in the logcat?

Comment: I made the changes suggested by Peter Haddad below but I get the same response. I added the else statement and a log to see if it hits the else but it does not, in fact it assigns the String to null.

Comment: Part of me wonders about the formatting of the E-Mail. Have you tried using a simple document name temporarily, just to see if you can hit that?

Comment: I have getting just the first name too but it is of no use :/

Comment: My best guess is that you're using `adminUser` outside of `onSuccess`, before it has been loaded. All code that needs data from Firestore, must be inside `onSuccess`, or be called from there. That's why your `onComplete` *does* work, since all code that uses the data is right in the method there.

Comment: But why is the `user` null then?